# Can I have a named integral constant for using across stored procedures in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to have something similar to a C++ integer constant that I could use across different stored T-SQL procedures:

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE STATE = IsBeingProcessed;
```

with `IsBeingProcessed` being a named integer constant equal to say `4`.

Is it possible in T-SQL?

Comment: There are several SO posts tackling constants in SQL - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370737/best-pattern-for-state-constants-in-sql-server-dbproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `User Defined Function` in the `master` table which simply does the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsBeingProcessed
(
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 4
END
```

Then this could be called like:

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE STATE = dbo.IsBeingProcessed();
```

Comment: This does have the disadvantage that SQL Server won't "sniff" the UDF value in order to determine more accurate cardinality estimates.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a config table with id, name and value populated with 'BeingProcessed' and 4 and join to the table. Would also foreign key it if possible. This also allows for the status definition to be updated as a table update. i.e. Business decide to change the name from being processed to awaiting processing.

Comment: +1 this is the right answer and the most accepted way to store application/global configuration.