# How to use constants for enums in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, enums, constants

How do people deal with constants in SQL that represent things like enums in software?

For example, I have an enum in my C# project

```
enum SocialMedia
{
Twitter = 1,
Facebook = 2
}
```

in the database, ideally I don't really want to write things like:

```
WHERE SocialMediaType = 2
```

(also next week I might add to the enum, such as Instagram = 3 and this would possibly need lots of stored procedures to change)

Comment: Create table `SocialMedia` containing key value pairs: {Twitter,1},{Facebook,2} etc.

Comment: Regardless of what you use you will still have to change your stored procedures etc. Why would you think `SocialMediaType = 2` is any different (maintenance wise) to `SocialMediaType = Facebook`?

Comment: Similar here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370737/best-pattern-for-state-constants-in-sql-server-dbproj